# Umlauts in Windows text files not recognized under Ubuntu

Tags: windows, files, encoding

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and right now need to use both Windows and Ubuntu depending on the context. One problem I encountered is that Ubuntu does not seem to recognize umlauts and such (which are pretty essential, since I write in German) in text files created under Windows. Instead I just see a � symbol. This also translates to pdftex output where these appear as "ï¿1⁄2".

Since this issue appears both in gedit and eclipse (and through LaTeX) it cannot be cause by the viewer. But it can't really be a problem of the file encoding either, can it? Under Windows the same files worked just fine. (I do, however, not know what the encoding is and was not able to figure that out using both gedit and the file manager.)

What's the cause of this behaviour and how can I prevent it?

---

Edit:

Output of `file -i document.tex`:

```
document.tex: text/x-tex; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Output of `locale`:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: The Windows files are probably using one of the windows encodings instead of UTF8. Please [edit] your question and post the output of `file -i foo.txt` (where `foo.txt` is one of the problematic text files). Also post the output of `locale`.

Comment: @terdon: You're right, it was indeed the encoding. I changed it under Windows and now everything works fine.
Since I don't know how to change the encoding under Ubuntu: Could you write an answer explaining that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the files are using the `iso-8859-1` which does not recognize umlauts. The simplest solution is to change the encoding of the files:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 document.tex > newdoc.tex
```

To do this for all tex files in your current directory, run this:

```
for f in *tex; do mv "$f" "$f".bak && iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 "$f".bak > "$f"; done
```

The command above will first rename each `.tex` file to `filename.tex.bak`, then change the encoding of the copy and save it as `filename.tex`. So, if you have a file named `foo.tex`, you will end up with a file called `foo.bak.tex` with the original encoding and the `foo.tex` with the UTF8 encoding.

---

Another problem you are likely to encounter is that Windows uses `\r\n` as a line ending while Linux & co use `\n` alone. You are therefore likely to want to change this when working on Linux. To convert windows line endings to Unix style, do

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' filename
```